# terraform conditional deploy doesn't work in depends on property

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have two projects:

1. I have to provide Managed Identity access to storage account
2. I don't have to.

As the modules are same, i'm trying to create the same module work for both the situations.
The Managed Identity is passed from other modules. In some situations the ID is null or empty. How can i ignore the code below in this case.

```
locals {
  # check if managed id is null: If so do not deploy permissions
  conditional_value = var.managed_id != "" ? 0 : 1
}

data "azurerm_subscription" "primary" {}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "assignmipermissions" {
  for_each             = var.adls
  scope                = "/subscriptions/${data.azurerm_subscription.primary.subscription_id}/resourceGroups/${var.resourcegpname}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/${var.resource}"
  role_definition_name = "Storage Blob Data Reader"
  principal_id         = var.managed_id 
  depends_on = [
    local.conditional_value
  ]
}
```

The depends on property doesn't work here.
What am i doing wrong.

thank you

Comment: You can define an output in the module and create a dependency that way. But since I don't know if you can edit the module I am not sure how to do it otherwise.

Comment: You want to skip entire `azurerm_role_assignment` block if `conditional_value == 0`?

Comment: @Marcin yes, if the value is null. I would like to skip it.

Comment: Why do you need `for_each` then?

Comment: @MarkoE I already tested removing that part and use count function. But then it says : var.managed_id cannot be used as its "know after apply"

Comment: How were you planning on making it dynamic if you are not going to provide the value for the variable? I'm having a hard time understanding where is it coming from (module, that's ok) and how would you map it to the variable value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to conditionally create `azurerm_role_assignment.assignmipermissions`, then it should be:

```
for_each             = local.conditional_value == 1 ? var.adls : {}
```

Comment: This won't work as it requires the value to be present during the plan.

Comment: @csuser According to your code, `conditional_value` is fully defined during the plan.

Comment: the managed_id comes from a different module and the plan cannot be created as the value is not present.